# How can I make it so that python can check a SystemError in the command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Each time I run the code it always thinks there is a system error even though there might not be

```
def Check():
    if SystemError:
        Label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Error: Invalid Version\nor already installed', bg="lightblue")
        Label3.config(font=('Ariel', 12), fg='red')
        canvas.create_window(150,330, window=Label3)
    else:
        success = tk.Label(root, text='Success!', bg="lightblue")
        success.config(font=('Ariel', 12), fg='green')
        canvas.create_window(150,330, window=success)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the code with a try block:

```
try:
    code_that_may_raise_an_error()
    # continue here when there was no error
except SystemError:
    # handle the error here
else:
    # handle the error free case here
```

Have a look at online [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) or the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more informations

That being said, it is not a good sign that this error is raised and there is probably a reason for it that should be taken care of.